# SugarCRM - How to add "More Info" icon that displays module "Description" field on mouseover

Tags: sugarcrm, customization

This is for SugarCRM v6.3

I need to add a "More Info" icon to the History subpanel, which, when moused-over, displays the relevant module's Description field, similar to how the More Info icon works in the Accounts ListView.

For starters I added new "History/metadata" folders to custom/modules/ and copied the subpaneldefs.php file from the core History/metadata folder.

In the subpaneldefs file, at the end of each of the module's column definitions, I added this as a test:

```
array ( 'customCode' => '<img src="themes/Sugar/images/info_inline.png"></img>', ),
```

That didn't seem to affect anything at all.

Not sure if it was just that I needed more than an image for the column to show, I then tried adding all of the code I **thought** was supposed to go there:

```
array ( 
'name' => 'nothing', 
'module' => 'Notes', 
'related_fields' => array ('id'), 
'customCode' => '<a id="adspan_{$ID}" href="index.php?module=Notes&action=DetailView&record={$ID}" onmouseover="return SUGAR.util.getAdditionalDetails(\'Notes\',\'{$ID}\',\'adspan_{$ID}\');" onmouseout="return SUGAR.util.clearAdditionalDetailsCall()"><img src="themes/Sugar/images/info_inline.png"></img></a>'
```

),
This is, as you can see, intended for the Notes in the History subpanel, and I changed it accordingly for each of the other modules' column definitions in the subpaneldefs.php file. I modeled the code after some custom code I found that someone else here at work did for a dashlet, which shows details when an account name is moused over.

Unfortunately, that didn't work, either.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is by defining a new SugarWidget field for the field in question. Here's a good guide I found for it:

http://www.mediaart.lt/programming/sugarcrm-adding-custom-field-in-subpanel/